# I am not able to understand why the normal reaction force between A and B is zero in this following question

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, forces, free-body-diagram

why is the normal reaction force zero(given in solutions )even when the relative acceleration between the two bodies is zero in x direction (so they must be in contact with each other)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

"In contact" is not a sufficient condition for the normal reaction to exist. Normal reaction arises when one body is pressed against another.

Answer (score 0):

For there to be a reaction force between A and B, something needs to press them together. There's nothing pressing them together in this image - gravity acts fully downwards; there is no horizontal component.

Answer (score 0):

To be fair, in real life, there would be a normal force because the rope would not be perfectly straight, and the two blocks would bump in against each other.

However, because we can assume that nothing is pressing these boxes together, there are no normal forces between them.

Suppose there were normal forces between them, then you would have an unbalanced force and the blocks would immediately bounce away from each other, which is not the case.

Answer (score 0):

Physical contact alone does not imply a normal force exists.

Your instinct may be correct in that there *is* a horizontal force here, but it is entirely reacted through the pulley, to body $B$, to the friction in the floor.  If there were no friction in the floor, body $B$ would start to move to the right, but *not* because it's being pushed by $A$.  [image: see sketch]